# How to fix Java org.usb4java.javax.Services was not found error?

Tags: java

I am trying to add an USB event listener using javaX. I used following code to implement the listener.

```
import javax.usb.*;
import javax.usb.event.*;

public class USBEventListener implements UsbServicesListener {

    private final WinController controller;
    private UsbServices usbServices;


    public USBEventListener(WinController _controller){

        controller = _controller;
        try {
            usbServices = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
            usbServices.addUsbServicesListener(this);
        } catch (UsbException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void usbDeviceAttached(UsbServicesEvent usbServicesEvent) {

        controller.readUSBDevices();
        System.out.println("Device Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void usbDeviceDetached(UsbServicesEvent usbServicesEvent) {

        controller.readUSBDevices();
        System.out.println("Device Detached");

    }
}
```

However when tried to use it, I get a usb exception and the traceback is as below:

```
javax.usb.UsbException: The UsbServices implementation class 

org.usb4java.javax.Services was not found : org.usb4java.javax.Services
    at usb.api@1.0.2/javax.usb.UsbHostManager.createUsbServices(Unknown Source)
    at usb.api@1.0.2/javax.usb.UsbHostManager.getUsbServices(Unknown Source)
    at com.kanishkawithanawasam.winboot.winboot/com.kanishkawithanawasam.winboot.winboot.config.USBEventListener.<init>(USBEventListener.java:17)
    at com.kanishkawithanawasam.winboot.winboot/com.kanishkawithanawasam.winboot.winboot.config.WinController.start(WinController.java:37)
    at com.kanishkawithanawasam.winboot.winboot/com.kanishkawithanawasam.winboot.winboot.WinBootMain.start(WinBootMain.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Further information:

- JDK: OpenJDK 20.0.1
- JavaX version 1.0.2
- Platform: MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 (22F82)

Please can someone help me to solve this Issue? I tried searching on the internet and the documentation but could not find a solution.